# python selenium presence_of_element_located timeout

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

two elements displayed in one page by selenium, i can find one but another got an error.

url:[base_url](https://sou.autohome.com.cn/zonghe?q=%BA%BA%C0%BC%B4%EF&pvareaid=3311667&mq=)

code:

```
element1 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'soudiv')))
print('element1:', element1)
element2 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cresult')))
print(element2)
```

console output:

```
element1: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="562daf934cfc22c3a31b17759d9a7502", element="0.8160783993595944-2")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/msxf/Documents/pythonProject/autohome/spider.py", line 56, in <module> start()
File "/Users/msxf/Documents/pythonProject/autohome/spider.py", line 44, in start
element2 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cresult')))
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

html:
[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj7va.jpg)

Comment: how much wait you have given? and try to increase it. It may solve your issue.

Comment: I don't see any effective usecase for `presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'soudiv'))` and `presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cresult'))`. Edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I try it and it works, this is my `Waits`

```
...
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

...

soudiv = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'soudiv')))
print(soudiv)
cresult = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'cresult')))
print(cresult)
```

**Output**

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d9cf0d2b2875a6a939cc2de50421f1d1", element="0.4909859897090536-1")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d9cf0d2b2875a6a939cc2de50421f1d1", element="0.4909859897090536-2")>
```

Comment: Hi, the whole detail is i have two pages A and B, A is homepage and it's website is "https://www.autohome.com.cn", A has a search field, input keyword can get page B, for example B's website is "https://sou.autohome.com.cn/zonghe?q=%BA%BA%C0%BC%B4%EF&pvareaid=3311667&mq=", if i visit B directly, it works too, but if i visit page A and searching keyword in A to get B, when B displayed, find elements, i get that error.